# Tabular into different rows within the table environment

Tags: tables, floats

I have three tabular environments that I would like to put within the same table... The problem is that they are too large to stay in a single row and I don't know how to break a row of tables so that it becomes divided into two. My code is

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\centerline{
\begin{tabular}
.....arguments...
\end{tabular}
\quad
\begin{tabular}
.....arguments...
\end{tabular}
\quad
\begin{tabular}
.....arguments...
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
```

Can you help me with this??
Manu

Answer (score 4):

Tabular environments are just positioned like big letters so put a blank line between them, and possibly `\centering` at the start of the table. Also If you use the `[]` option to table it is best to include `p` and probably `t` as well. Also, remove the `\centerline` command which should never be used in LaTeX and is the reason that the existing code does not linebreak)